# Difficulty with Boolean and arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

Here, I am trying to write a code that takes a list of integers as a parameter and searches for the value 7. The function will return a boolean value representing true if 7 is in the list and false if it is not. This is what I have tried so far:

[image]

Could it be something with my else statement? Do I end it too soon? Or not soon enough?

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Comment: Get rid of the `else` and it will work fine. The construct is called `if-else`, not `for-else`.

Comment: This is not Python, you can't have an `else` clause on `for`. It can only be used with `if`.

Comment: I realize this is probably a coding exercise, but if you favor brevity, you could do something as simple as `function find_value(list) { return list.includes(7); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration of the if statement is wrong. The `else` tag is on the wrong line. If you use else, it should come after the `if`-block.

But moving the `else`-block up, won't fix your function, because it will only return `true` if the first element in your array is a **7**.

There are many good ways to do it, such as using **higher order functions**, but as it seems you are new to the language.

EDIT: Therefore, I would suggest one of the two simple ways below:

1) You could store the number of *7s* found in the array in a `for` loop. Afterwards return `false` if the number of *7s* **is 0** or `true` if it the number is **higher than 0**

2) Another, much quicker way would be to return `true` in the `for`-loop when you encounter a *7* and after the `for`-loop just `return false`. Because a `return` statement exits the scope - which is your function - not only the `for`-loop would come to an end but also your function would return `true` much earlier.

For the second option, your function would look like this:

```
function find_value(list) {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i] == 7) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: Although it's a learning experience, I very much disagree with your proposed solution. If you had an array of 5,000 items and the first item was `7`, your solution will continue evaluating the other 4,999 items.

Comment: Yes you are correct. A quicker way would be to return `true` directly when a *7* is encountered, but I wanted to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript already has a function to do this. [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). You use it like this:

```
const containsSeven = list.includes(7)
```

If you are looking for something more complicated, like whether an item is an object and contains a particular key value pair for example, you can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Any reason to use `some` and write your own comparison instead of just using `includes`? Genuinely curious.

Comment: You're right. Includes is much better. Slipped my mind from the array prototype list. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, I think includes is much better. I think I went to some() naturally because I am always checking for something more complex. Again, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use an array and use includes as per ECMA2016 like below:

```
if([2,5,7].includes(value)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

or with list

```
var flag = false;

for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
{   if(arguments[i] == this) { flag = true; break; }}

return flag;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can coerces to `boolean` the result of [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which returns the value of the **first element** in the `array` that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is returned.

Code:

```js
const list1 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const findTheNumber = (arr, num) => !!arr.find(n => n === num);

console.log(findTheNumber(list1, 7));
console.log(findTheNumber(list2, 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function search(list , value){      // Value = 7; 
    return true ? list.indexOf(value) > -1 : false
}
```

[image: Proof]

Comment: Again... why are you using a ternary operator? You are quite literally saying *"If `true` is `true`..."*. Also `indexOf` is case-sensitive. `return list.indexOf(value) > -1` would work just fine.

Comment: @TylerRoper It is the simple one if list has index of value then return true otherwise return false.

Comment: @TylerRoper Can you please tell me , what's wrong in my answer.

Comment: I literally just did...? `indexOf` is case-sensitive. I'm still very confused about the ternary operator but I've downvoted it because it simply doesn't work.

Comment: The code in the image that you've attached is *not the same as the code in your answer* though. It's `index` **`Of`** , not `index` **`of`** . I also don't know how else to explain the ternary operator thing. Would you ever write `if (true) { ... } else { ... }`? Because that is literally what  `true ? ... : ...` is.

Comment: @TylerRoper Yaa It was type mistake, I have correct it. Please check it

Comment: @TylerRoper Welcome and thanks you for showing my mistake , I'll take care about it